# Excessive processing power being used, is this part inefficient?

Tags: bash

I have written a short bash script to read a csv file line by line and pass this to a python script. The running of it seems to be eating up all my processing power so I just wanted to check if there is anything inefficient about how I do this before I start going through the python code (which is probably where the problem is, but just in case)

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

CSV_NAME='path/to/csv/to/read.csv'
mass_higgstools='path/to/python/script.py'
output_path='path/for/output.csv'

IFS='
'
header_line=($(cat $CSV_NAME))
count=0

{
        read #Double read to skip the header line of data csv

        while IFS=',' read -ra line
        do
                echo ${count}
                count=$((count+1))
                input=("${output_path}" "${header_line}" ${line[@]})

                python ${mass_higgstools} ${input[@]} # Here we run, and pass variables to, a 2HDM higgstools script

        done

} < $CSV_NAME
```

It has been running for about 24hrs on a csv of ~16,000 rows and it is only halfway through! Running on a 1-2 row csv takes less than a second, and running `ps aux` tells me it is somehow using roughly 100% of my CPU. This is laptop has Intel® Core™ i7-6820HQ CPU @ 2.70GHz × 8 !

Comment: Starting a new python process for each line is going to be expensive. Why not have the python script read the file itself?

Comment: it seems like `header_line=($(cat $CSV_NAME))` would have more than just the `header_line` "record" in it. Did you chk? Good luck.

Comment: @Barmar I adapted my python script from a jupyter notebook, its some particle physics code that was always designed to global initialisation of extra particles(set up as a class), its originally written in C++ with a python interface ontop. It was never meant to change the particle masses once initialised, (which is one of the main things I want to do), none of the functions work properly if I don't declare it globally. As I am not well versed in C++ I thought this was a simpler solution, but maybe not! Unfortunately the devs I e-mailed 1 week + ago haven't gotten back to me yet to help

Comment: do the arrays contain what you think they contain (ie, what does `typeset -p header_line` and `typeset -p input` show as the contents of these arrays)? what steps have you taken to debug/analyze the performance of `script.py` (this is a black hole for us as we have no idea what it's doing so 'the sky's the limit' when it comes to potential performance issues); generally speaking, reading 16K lines should take no more than a couple seconds ... what's been going on for the rest of the other 24 hrs is impossible to say without more debug/monitoring details

Comment: `${input[@]}` should be in double quotes. Also `${line[@]}`

Comment: @shellter I certainly thought I had...it gets spilt into a list that becomes a new csv header in the python script, it seems to have the correct one. I will double check separately now if it just returns the first line. Thanks!

Comment: Why are you reading the entire file into `header_line` when you just want the first line?  Use `header_line=$(head -1 "$CSV_FILE")`

Comment: How many fields per line?

Comment: If `x` is an array variable, `$x` is the same as `${x[0]}`

Comment: @markp-fuso turns out the arrays didn't contain the exact bit I wanted, but thats fixed now.

Comment: @Barmar I'm not sure how but I was convinced I was only reading in the first line into header_line, thank-you for that!

Comment: @glennjackman each line from the csv file has 78 fields. I found the easiest way to pass everything I wanted to python was by putting everything into a single array. I suppose it doesn't all need to go through there (the output_file string, even the header_line, but reading them in on the python side 16,000 times seemed silly.

Answer (score 3):

You aren't making use of all 8 cores, so consider using **GNU Parallel** to run 8 Python jobs at a time.

Try just cutting 16 lines, without a header, from your CSV and saving it in a file called `params.txt`, then run:

```
parallel --bar python NONVARYINGPARAMETERS :::: params.txt
```

It will keep 8 Python jobs running at a time till they are all done. The `--bar` will show a progress bar. Each job will receive the non-varying parameters followed by whatever is on one line of your `params.txt`

Depending how your CSV looks, you may need `parallel --colsep ','` to say columns in your input file are separated by commas.

If, for some reason - maybe the memory required is excessively large - you want to run fewer jobs in parallel, try `parallel -j 4 ...` to run 4 at a time.

Comment: I didn't expect this to require that! But it is a good idea, thanks! Can I still write all my output to the same csv file while doing that? Or would I need to do one for each core and concat them after?

Comment: It depends how the Python scripts write their output and if you need to retain ordering. You can make jobs under **GNU Parallel** use *"line-buffering"* which will intermix lines from all jobs but never split in the middle of a line, or you can use *"grouped"* output which will put all lines from each job together in a group. Or you can use `tagged` output so lines from each job are tagged with the job name so you can sort/split afterwards. If you need the output from job1 followed by job2 followed by job3, use `-k` to `keep` ordering.

Comment: You can keep the header with `--header 1`. If useful, you can then even address each variable as `{col-name1}` .. `{col-nameN}`.

Answer (score 2):

```
header_line=($(cat $CSV_NAME))
```

header_line will be an array containing all the whitespace-separated **words** of the file. If the first line of the file happens to have no spaces in it, then the first element of the array will indeed be the first line.

```
        while IFS=',' read -ra line
        ...
                input=("${output_path}" "${header_line}" ${line[@]})
```

Similarly, if any of the fields of the line array contain whitespace, then the `input` array won't contain what you think it does.

You probably want this, with all the quotes

```bash
{
    IFS= read -r header_line        # first line
    read                            # second line
    while IFS=, read -ra line; do   # all the other lines
        echo "$((count++))"
        input=("${output_path}" "${header_line}" "${line[@]}")
        python "${mass_higgstools}" "${input[@]}"
    done

} < "$CSV_NAME"
```

Although bash while-read loops are slow, 16,000 lines should not be a challenge. I'd wonder what your python code is doing getting invoked 16,000 times in a row.

Comment: *"I'd wonder what your python code is doing..."* Agreed! ... put another way, set up a manual cmdline test like `time python "${mass_higgstools}" "${input[@]}"` (where you have filled in 1 set of values) and see how long it takes. All the above comments are useful but I don't see anything in your shell coding that will reduce your runs from hours to minutes. The result of the `time python ..` will tell you if you are processing bound. AND running with `gnu-parallel` or `xargs` is you best bet to reduce run time (IMHO). Good luck.

Comment: The code set `IFS` to newline before `header_line=($(cat $CSV_NAME))` so it splits it into lines, not words.

Comment: Thank-you! It is running faster now, though it definitely seems to be slowing down as it gets further through the input csv file, which is bizarre. My code is checking the validity of my scans of the available parameter space left by the analyses at CERN and through theoretical calculations for a physics model where there are additional Higgs bosons. Each line is a different point I have found that passes some constraints previously and now I need to check in something called Higgstools, that's why there are so many! All the variables are continuous, so theres a lot of possibilities!

Comment: The python part is mainly just reading in variables to particle classes and setting other physical variables to values from the csv file. I do have it read the output file into a pandas dataframe purely to append the latest point results to it and save it again, which is obviously getting bigger each time but I don't see how that would cause a slow down that is continuously getting worse  with time. The code I call to check the model point is a) very fast when run on a single point and b) written in C++ with a python interface rather than python, so I'm very unsure why its so slow

Comment: @shelter Thanks! Time for me to go pull apart the python script it is then!